# ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame - How am I supposed to erase drawn rectangle?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Consider the following code:

```
Dim recSelection As Rectangle?
Dim pntDown As Point?
Dim pntMove As Point?

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)

    pntDown = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    pntMove = pntDown
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(e As Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If Me.recSelection.HasValue Then
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(recSelection.Value, Me.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed)
    End If

    pntDown = Nothing
    pntMove = Nothing
    recSelection = Nothing

    MyBase.OnMouseUp(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

    If pntDown.HasValue Then
        If recSelection.HasValue Then
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(recSelection.Value, Me.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed)
        End If

        pntMove = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(Math.Max(Math.Min(e.X, Me.ClientSize.Width), 0), Math.Max(Math.Min(e.Y, Me.ClientSize.Height), 0)))

        recSelection = GetRectangle(pntDown, pntMove)

        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(Me.recSelection.Value, Me.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetRectangle(pointA As Point, pointB As Point) As Rectangle
    Dim intLeft As Integer = Math.Min(pointA.X, pointB.X)
    Dim intTop As Integer = Math.Min(pointA.Y, pointB.Y)

    Dim intRight As Integer = Math.Max(pointA.X, pointB.X)
    Dim intBottom As Integer = Math.Max(pointA.Y, pointB.Y)

    Return Rectangle.FromLTRB(intLeft, intTop, intRight, intBottom)
End Function
```

Basically I want to draw a selection rectangle over a control and its children. In [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it says that to erase the rectangle, I should recall the `DrawReversibleFrame` method with the same parameters used to draw it in the first place.

Unfortunately, in my case that doesn't seem to work. The previous selection rectangle remains painted over the control. At one point I can end up having multiple selection rectangles accumulating:

[image]

(not the actual screenshot, I used MS Paint to reproduce the effect)

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the very same code shown in the documentation and the behavior is the exact same! Might have something to do with my specific display settings. Also I'm using Windows 8.1. Could that be the issue? I'll try deploying on another system tomorrow.

Comment: You have to call it twice, the 2nd time passing the *exact* same rectangle.  That erases it again.  The "reversable" part of the name.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm confused. I do call the method twice in `OnMouseMove` method. First time to erase the previous rectangle, second to draw the new one. MSDN seems to do it the exact same manner. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce the problem.  But it is troublesome code, the kind that gets programmers that use CreateGraphics() in trouble all the time as well.  It won't work correctly if the background redraws itself, that erases the frame and now the second call doesn't erase anymore but leaves a visible rectangle.  You shouldn't be using this, it isn't 1992 anymore.  Flickers like a cheap motel anyway.  Call Invalidate(), use e.Graphics.DrawRectangle() in OnPaint().  If that's too slow then make the background image fast by paying attention to the size and the pixel format.

Comment: @HansPassant using OnPaint was my first idea but I've stumbled on a problem with it: the rectangle won't paint over child controls. I need a solution that will paint the frame over everything within the control.

Comment: Hmya, on overlay is the proper way to do that.  But you won't like it, you're looking for the quick fix.  I gave you a hint what to look for, at least override the form's OnPaint and OnPaintBackground methods and set pntDown back to Nothing.  Btw, putting Option Strict On at the top of your source files is going to make you write better code.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/creating-mouse-drag-box

Comment: @HansPassant I'll give it a try tomorrow. By then I should have cleaned all the blood in my eyes. :) (no offense meant, code actually looks quite clever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the "mask" solution, as proposed by Hans in the comments above, with a few ameliorations:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public NotInheritable Class RectangleDrawer

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Draw(parent As Form) As Rectangle

        ' Record the start point
        Dim startingPoint As Point = parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

        ' Create a transparent form on top of control and display it
        Using mask As New MaskForm(parent, startingPoint)
            mask.ShowDialog(parent)
        End Using

        Dim pos As Point = parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

        Dim x As Integer = Math.Min(startingPoint.X, pos.X)
        Dim y As Integer = Math.Min(startingPoint.Y, pos.Y)
        Dim w As Integer = Math.Abs(startingPoint.X - pos.X)
        Dim h As Integer = Math.Abs(startingPoint.Y - pos.Y)

        Return New Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
    End Function

    Private Class MaskForm
        Inherits Form

        Friend Sub New(parent As Form, startingPoint As Point)
            MyBase.New()

            Me._StartingPoint = startingPoint

            Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta
            Me.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
            Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual

            Me.DoubleBuffered = True 'Prevents flickering (credits to Mike)

            Me.Size = parent.ClientSize
            Me.Location = parent.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
        End Sub

        Dim _StartingPoint As Point

        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowWithoutActivation As Boolean
            Get
                ' Don't steal focus away
                Return True
            End Get
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.Load(e)

            ' Grab the mouse
            Me.Capture = True
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e as MouseEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

            ' Repaint the rectangle
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(e as MouseEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

            ' Done, close mask
            Me.Close()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e as PaintEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)

            ' Draw the current rectangle
            Dim pos As Point = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

            Using pen As New Pen(Brushes.Black)
                pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _StartingPoint.X, _StartingPoint.Y, pos.X, mPos.Y)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pos.X, _StartingPoint.Y, pos.X, pos.Y)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pos.X, pos.Y, _StartingPoint.X, pos.Y)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _StartingPoint.X, pos.Y, _StartingPoint.X, _StartingPoint.Y)
            End Using
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

Words doesn't even begin to describe how much I hate it, but that's still the best workaround I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution, and this solution from Crono works perfectly.  The only improvement I will add is to eliminate the flickering of the rectangle.  Here is how:

1. Have the class inherit `Form`
2. Remove the class property `Private Shared mMask As Form`
3. Also, remove `mMask = New Form()`
4. In the *Draw* function, replace `mMask` with `Me`
5. After *Me.Location = parent.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)*, enter the line

   `Me.DoubleBuffered = True 'Prevent Flickering`
6. In *DoCapture* replace *mMask.Capture = True* with

   `sender.Capture = True`
7. In *MouseMove* replace *mMask.Invalidate()* with

   `sender.Invalidate()`
8. In *MouseUp* replace *mMask.Close()* with

   `sender.Close()`
9. In *PaintRectangle* replace *Dim pos As Point = mMask.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)* with

   `Dim pos As Point = sender.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)`

Enjoy non flickering!

Comment: Wow, thanks! I noticed the flickering too but was too lazy to find out how to get rid of it. :D I will try your suggestions on my end and incorporate it in my original answer (with credits to you, of course). +1

Comment: Quick note: in my real code I did use a derived form. If you do too then I'd suggest that you override OnXXXX methods instead of handling events. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified answer I made to another post. I don't use VB so I don't want to clutter this topic with an answer in a different language. But, the pseudo logic for what you're trying to do is this:

MouseDown:

1. Draw a rectangle using `DrawReversibleFrame`.
2. Save rectangle bounds.

MouseMove (w/ left button down):

1. Redraw previous rectangle to erase, using `DrawReversibleFrame`.
2. Calculate the next rectangle using new mouse coordinates.
3. Draw next rectangle using `DrawReversibleFrame`.
4. Save rectangle bounds.
5. Rinse/Repeat indefinitely.

MouseUp:

1. Redraw last rectangle to erase, using `DrawReversibleFrame`.
2. Call `Invalidate(true)` for good measure.

To Troubleshoot: Create a wrapper function for `DrawReversibleFrame()` calls. After drawing the rectangle, print the rectangle bounds to the debug window. Verify that each rectangle is drawn twice as you drag your mouse across the control.

I hope this helps.

Note: In response to your post, there is about a 0% chance that your problem is related to the functioning of your computer or Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately though, in my scenario this wouldn't have done it. Suspending / resuming application drawing would have prevented selection targets from painting themselves as selected while the selection is still in progress.

Comment: No Problem. I'm happy to contribute. I do see your point. For that kind application, selected controls should resume/paint/suspend as they fall under the focus rectangle The goal is still to prevent erroneous paint messages from ruining your rectangle. This is also a great technique for resizing a form without having docked controls stutter as they try to keep up with changes to the form's bounds. You can just make the whole thing snap into place when the mouse is released. Anyhow, take care.